# iPhone App Design Templates

Tags: resources

Are there any good sites to buy iPhone / iPad Application design templates?

Think website templates, but for iOS devices.

During research, I found [Tapptics](http://www.tapptics.com/), which is a good start.

However ideally I am looking for sites offering templates that

- Can be purchased separately
- Do not require attribution
- With a wide variety of styles

Any format (PSD, AI, Key, Xcode Project) is fine.

Comment: I'd suggest migrating it back to graphic design. Otherwise, close it.

Comment: I second the suggestion to move it back to graphic design... the user is looking for **graphic** templates, not wireframe or interaction templates.

Comment: As the person with the question, I also agree this is more of a task for graphic design as this does not pertain to creating the user experience or usage flow but the graphic "eye candy" layer.

Comment: Im not sure whats being asked for.  Design patterns?  or prototyping tools (like Balsamiq has iPhone templates) or something else.  Its a good question to ask about design patterns for the iPhone.  Ive seen some, like gesture usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try this template, by Geoff Teehan http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-gui-psd-v4/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a roundup of many templates in different formats. Also different phones.

http://aext.net/2011/08/roundup-of-useful-and-free-smart-phones-gui-psd-packs/